# xamarin UITableViewController cell dequeue

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have a UITableViewController with around 100 cells, In one of thoses cells (let's say the first) I want to draw a subview like this:

```
UILabel l = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10f, 10f, 200f, 20f));
l.Text = "test";
l.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
```

The problem it's that once the screen have completely been scrolled up the first cell on the second screen still have the view, same goes on 3rd, 4th screen etc...

I'm suspecting the

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_section1CellId);
```

not working correctly, the cell content isn't cleanup when the cell is reused, so any cell reusing the same view display it.

A sample of code:

**table view controller**

```
public class MyViewController : UITableViewController
{
    public MyViewController()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

        TableView.DataSource = new MainTableDataSource();
        TableView.Delegate = new MainTableDelegate(this);
        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }

}
```

**Table data source**

```
public class MainTableDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
{
    private List<string> _items;
    private string _section1CellId;

    public MainTableDataSource()
    {
        _section1CellId = "cellid";
        _items = new List<string>()
        {   
            "Battlewise Valor",  "Cavalry Pegasus",  "Celestial Archon",  "Chained to the Rocks",  "Chosen by Heliod",  "Dauntless Onslaught",  "Decorated Griffin",  "Divine Verdict",  "Elspeth, Sun's Champion",  "Ephara's Warden",  
            "Evangel of Heliod",  "Fabled Hero",  "Favored Hoplite",  "Gift of Immortality",  "Glare of Heresy",  "Gods Willing",  "Heliod, God of the Sun",  "Heliod's Emissary",  "Hopeful Eidolon",  "Hundred-Handed One",  
            "Lagonna-Band Elder",  "Last Breath",  "Leonin Snarecaster",  "Observant Alseid",  "Ordeal of Heliod",  "Phalanx Leader",  "Ray of Dissolution",  "Scholar of Athreos",  "Setessan Battle Priest",  "Setessan Griffin",  
            "Silent Artisan",  "Soldier of the Pantheon",  "Spear of HeliodLegendary ",  "Traveling Philosopher",  "Vanquish the Foul",  "Wingsteed Rider",  "Yoked Ox",  "Annul",  "Aqueous Form",  "Artisan of Forms",  "Benthic Giant", 
            "Bident of Thassa",  "Breaching Hippocamp",  "Coastline Chimera",  "Crackling Triton",  "Curse of the Swine",  "Dissolve",  "Fate Foretold",  "Gainsay",  "Griptide",  "Horizon Scholar",  "Lost in a Labyrinth",  
            "Master of Waves",  "Meletis Charlatan",  "Mnemonic Wall",  "Nimbus Naiad",  "Omenspeaker",  "Ordeal of Thassa",  "Prescient Chimera",  "Prognostic Sphinx",  "Sea God's Revenge",  "Sealock Monster",  "Shipbreaker Kraken", 
            "Stymied Hopes",  "Swan Song",  "Thassa, God of the SeaLegendary ",  "Thassa's Bounty",  "Thassa's Emissary",  "Triton Fortune Hunter",  "Triton Shorethief",  "Triton Tactics",  "Vaporkin",  "Voyage's End",  "Wavecrash Triton",
            "Abhorrent Overlord",  "Agent of the Fates",  "Asphodel Wanderer",  "Baleful Eidolon",  "Blood-Toll Harpy",  "Boon of Erebos",  "Cavern Lampad",  "Cutthroat Maneuver",  "Dark Betrayal",  "Disciple of Phenax",  
            "Erebos, God of the DeadLegendary ",  "Erebos's Emissary",  "Felhide Minotaur",  "Fleshmad Steed",  "Gray Merchant of Asphodel",  "Hero's Downfall",  "Hythonia the CruelLegendary ",  "Insatiable Harpy",  "Keepsake Gorgon",  
            "Lash of the Whip",  "Loathsome Catoblepas",  "March of the Returned",  "Mogis's Marauder",  "Nighthowler",  "Ordeal of Erebos",  "Pharika's Cure",  "Read the Bones",  "Rescue from the Underworld",  "Returned Centaur",  
            "Returned Phalanx",  "Scourgemark",  "Sip of Hemlock",  "Thoughtseize",  "Tormented Hero",  "Viper's Kiss",  "Whip of ErebosLegendary ",  "Akroan Crusader",  "Anger of the Gods",  "Arena Athlete",  "Borderland Minotaur",  "Boulderfall",  "Coordinated Assault",  "Deathbellow Raider",  "Demolish",  "Dragon Mantle",  "Ember Swallower",  "Fanatic of Mogis",  "Firedrinker Satyr",  "Flamespeaker Adept",  "Hammer of PurphorosLegendary ",  
            "Ill-Tempered Cyclops",  "Labyrinth Champion",  "Lightning Strike",  "Magma Jet",  "Messenger's Speed",  "Minotaur Skullcleaver",  "Ordeal of Purphoros",  "Peak Eruption",  "Portent of Betrayal",  "Priest of Iroas",  
            "Purphoros, God of the ForgeLegendary ",  "Purphoros's Emissary",  "Rage of Purphoros",  "Rageblood Shaman",  "Satyr Rambler",  "Spark Jolt",  "Spearpoint Oread",  "Stoneshock Giant",  "Stormbreath Dragon",  
            "Titan of Eternal Fire",  "Titan's Strength",  "Two-Headed Cerberus",  "Wild Celebrants",  "Agent of Horizons",  "Anthousa, Setessan HeroLegendary ",  "Arbor Colossus",  "Artisan's Sorrow",  "Boon Satyr",  
            "Bow of NyleaLegendary ",  "Centaur Battlemaster",  "Commune with the Gods",  "Defend the Hearth",  "Fade into Antiquity",  "Feral Invocation",  "Hunt the Hunter",  "Karametra's Acolyte",  "Leafcrown Dryad"
        };
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        return "Items";
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return _items.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // For more information on why this is necessary, see the Apple docs
        var row = indexPath.Row;

        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_section1CellId);

        int n = (int) indexPath.IndexAtPosition(indexPath.Length - 1);

        if (cell == null)
        {
            // See the styles demo for different UITableViewCellAccessory
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, _section1CellId);
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;


        }

        string s = "";

        s = row + ":" + cell.Subviews.Count();


        if (row.Equals(5))
        {
            UILabel l = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10f, 10f, 200f, 20f));
            l.Text = "TOTO";
            l.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            //UIView v = new UIView(new RectangleF(10f, 10f, 20f, 20f));
            //v.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
            cell.Add(l);
        }

        if (row < 20)
        {

            cell.TextLabel.Text = _items[indexPath.Row];
        }

        s = s + ":" + cell.Subviews.Count();
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior.  When you DequeueReusableCell the cell that is returned may already contain content.  You need to be responsible for any cleanup and setting the values of the cell as appropriate for the new indexPath.

Comment: how comes in native objective C the cell is cleaned ? If I port the code in objC I have no problems with views not unloaded

Comment: from Apple's UITableViewCell docs: "The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell"

Comment: so what would be the proper way of cleaning the view ? I really don't feel like iterating over subviews to remove it one by one

Comment: Just clear the values you set, or set them to the appropriate values for the new cell.  If it's a custom cell you've created you should know what is there and what cleanup needs to be done.